# Highlight sections of a ggplot stacked bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# Create the data
library(tidyverse)
dat <- read.table(text = "A B C
                          1   23  234 324
                          2   34  534 12
                          3   56  324 124
                          4   34  234 124
                          5   123 534 654",
                  sep = "", 
                  header = TRUE) %>% 
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value") %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(ind = as.factor(rep(1:5)), 
         perc = value / sum(value)) %>% 
  arrange(variable, -perc) %>% 
  mutate(ordering = row_number())

# Plot the data
ggplot(dat, aes(variable, perc, fill = interaction(-ordering, variable))) + 
  geom_col(color = "black") + 
  facet_grid(~ variable, scales = "free_x") + 
  scale_fill_manual("ind", values = rep("grey", length(dat$variable))) + 
  # geom_col(data = dat %>% filter(ordering == 1), fill = "blue") %>% # line 23 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image: stacked bar]

How would I highlight the three largest sections of each stacked bar graph above? Basically I want the bottom block of each facet, "A", "B", and "C", to be highlighted in blue.

I would imagine it would be by un-commenting out the line I commented out above (line #23). Unfortunately, that does not work.

Comment: If I uncomment line #23 and change the pipe `%>%` to a plus `+` everything works as expected. I'd delete this question, but at this point I hope somebody else can eventually learn from this post. And if you have anything to add feel free to.

Comment: I would suggest delete it. This problem arose of using incorrect ggplot syntax (which you have correctly identified)